# SQL - Inserting a character into a string Based on Conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have column data. For example, EELMEX00001. I need to insert another zero after the letters. There by making the length 12. Can anyone help me with a query to do this. If the string is less than 11, insert another zero after the letters. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the position is always the same (which seems likely for your example), you can do:

```
select concat(left(col, 6), '0', right(col, 5))
```

If the position can vary, this is tricker in older versions of MySQL.  In MySQL 8+, you can do:

```
select concat(regexp_substr(col, '[^0-9]+', 1), '0', regexp_substr(col, '[0-9]+$', 1))
from (select 'EELMEX00001' as col) x
```

If you want to actually change the column:

```
update t
    set col = concat(left(col, 6), '0', right(col, 5))
    where col regexp '^[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{5}$';
```

Comment: Yes there will always be six letters to begin with. So this is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Tried this, no error but the column didn't update.: update `TableOne`
    set pr_my_num = concat(left(pr_my_num, 6), '0', right(pr_my_num, 5))
    where pr_my_num regexp '^[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{5}$';

Comment: @Eric . . . You can leave out the `WHERE` clause, if you know the current values are all consistent.  That should be matching the format.

Comment: Great, updating now. I will run this query on all of those records less than 12. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will impact on rows with LENGTH(Your_Column) = 11 only. All other values will remain same as they are now.

```
UPDATE your_Table
SET your_column = 
CASE 
    WHEN LENGTH(Your_Column) = 11 THEN CONCAT (your_column,'0') 
    ELSE your_column 
END;
```